# Nested flexbox does not work unless bullet points from ul are showing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, conflict

I'm doing a "Code Along" sort-of exercise by Colt Steele's web dev bootcamp on Udemy.
Essentially, adding justify-content: space-evenly to ul { doesn't do anything; the elements within ul sit on the left. A workaround I tried was commenting out display: inline from ul, li {, which does work, but bullet points show up. I'm following on the same file I downloaded from Udemy. Can you help me find what I'm missing? Thank you!
My code below:
PS: This is my very first post, I hope I formatted my question the right way.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    border: 2px solid black;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    /* DOES NOT SPACE EVENLY */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

ul,
li {
    /* CONFLICTS WITH justify-content: space-evenly INSIDE ul */
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 3em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Queries</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="starter.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <!-- FLEXBOX PARENT START -->
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <!-- FLEXBOX CHILD START -->
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <!-- FLEXBOX CHILD END -->
        </ul>
        <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
        <!-- FLEXBOX PARENT END -->
    </nav>
    <h1>Media Queries</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's because after you declare ul as flex container you set ul,li { display:inline}, so the ul is not a flex container and justify-content can't work

Comment: The _proper_ way to get rid of list bullets, is `list-style: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display: inline;` on your `ul, li` is affecting the `flex` you have on your `ul`. The proper way of removing the `:marker`'s on the `ul` is by using `list-style-type: none;` on your `li`. Doing this solves your `space-evenly` issue.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Media Queries</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="starter.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <!-- FLEXBOX PARENT START -->
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <!-- FLEXBOX CHILD START -->
      <li>
        <a href="#Home">Learn More</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Home">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#Home">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <!-- FLEXBOX CHILD END -->
    </ul>
    <a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
    <!-- FLEXBOX PARENT END -->
  </nav>
  <h1>Media Queries</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That `display: inline` is the first thing that catched my attention, as well. What I'm wondering is what's happening on Colt's file since I'm using his identical file and following what he does to the letter. If it was for me, I wouldn't have added `display: inline` in there because of `flex-direction: row`, which he doesn't use in the video, (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm learning as I go).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/psychocybernetics/wjgyf04u/3/ (here it does seem to work for some reason)

Comment: @psychocybernetics The difference is the code in your question has `display: inline` for the `ul` coming after the `display: flex;` in the sequence of the stylesheet. The one you linked has the `display: inline` coming first with the `display: flex;` coming second. Therefore, on your code in the question, the `display: inline` is recognized after the `display: flex;` and it is the one being picked up by the browser. You'll notice if you add `display: flex !important;` on your `ul` in the question it fixes the issue. Browser grabs those styles from top to bottom, therefore getting the `inline`.